# Plesk shows only default page

Tags: linux, centos, plesk

I use Plesk Onyx 17.8.11 on a CentOS vps and I am facing a problem with default pages.

First of all, when I go to any of my domains it shows me the plesk default page.

I already searched a lot for it, but nothing helped.

If you need more info feel free to ask me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

can you try repairing Plesk config

```
plesk repair all
```

Comment: do you see apache and nginx configuration loaded ?

Comment: Yes, it seems it is a configuration problem.